# Django token authentication without rest framework

Tags: python, django

I am required to make an API endpoint that receives XML in post request body. The XML format is given by a third party and can not be changed. I can't use the rest framework because the format of the XML is not in the form which rest framework expects. I decided to use the traditional Django requests with `xmltodict` library for parsing the XML. My code will be something like this:

In `views.py`:

```
def newOrderStatus(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        obj = readXML(request.body)
        obj.save()
```

Now what I want is to authenticate the request using a bearer token. Is there a way to do this or do I need to write my own middleware?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

you can use `@permission_classes` decorator :

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def newOrderStatus(request):
    obj = readXML(request.body)
    obj.save()
```